# How is a symbolic value stored in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

A symbolic value occupies 112 bytes of memory with Matlab (Symbolic Math toolbox). One can see this via the `whos` command.

I know that a floating-point value (in the numerical framework of Matlab) is stored according to the IEEE 754 standard. So, with 8 bytes (double precision): 52 bits for the mantissa, one bit for the sign, and 11 bits for the exponent.

What about the details of the storage of symbolic numbers? What standard is used?

Comment: If you type `edit sym` into the matlab terminal, you can see that symbols are stored as objects of the class `sym`. My guess is that the storage format is probably unique to MATLAB and doesn't follow any particular standard.

Comment: In addition the size reported by `whos` does not reflect the memory usage for a symbolic object/datatype. Type `edit sym` in your command window and explore, but much of this is hidden away in mex code.

Comment: Matlab questions are often answerable in one way or another iff they have a practical purpose. So I wonder whether you need this information (and for what), or perhaps it's just curiosity?

Answer (score 2):

The core of the symbolic math toolbox is mupad, a software which was developed by the "mupad research group" at the university of paderborn. If you want to get a rough idea how symbolic math works in Matlab works try searching there.

The `sym` object itself is some kind of wrapper porting the data into matlab. You can easily prove that the `sym` does not contain all relevant information. Create a `1000` digits constant, to hold this information more than 112 bytes are required but your `sym` still has the same size.